# Manage SSL Certificate in production environment (Spring application)

Tags: java, spring, https, ssl-certificate, pkix

I have developped a Spring application in a local environment (Tomcat Serveur 9.0.52 / JDK 1.0.8_291). This application call an external webservice from an https url.

In order to connect to this webservice, I had to update the jdk cacert manually
(Due to : `PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`).

I used the command : `keytool -import -alias abc -keystore  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -file abc.cer`

**Now, I have to deploy this .war on a production environment.**

**1- I would like to know what is the best practice to implement, in order to manage SSL certificate in production?**

**2- Do I have to update it manually every year?**

**3- Is there any other solution?**

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: The first question that comes to my mind here is: is this a service (i.e. its certificate) under your control? Would you know when the certificate of this service is updated?

The second one is: what type of certificate did you trust? Was it a root/intermediate/leaf certificate?

Comment: Non this ils ont a service under my control. And the only information that I have, is the final date of the actual certificate (september 2022). The certificate that I trusted was obtained from browser. Is there a méthod to know what kind of certificate is it? Thank you